# How to configure commands to get executed automatically when AWS ec2 instance cpu utilization goes above certain percentage

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

The commands on the instance that has high CPU like taking java thread dump, checking processes running and upload to s3

Comment: Where do you want to execute commands? On the same host? On some other host?

Comment: For the first part of triggering an alarm when cpu usage goes above a threshold, you can take a look at - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_AlarmAtThresholdEC2.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloudwatch to monitor the CPU and run command via SSM when the specific threshold is reached

Follow this document to set this up:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EC2_Run_Command.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).